# Create swift framework without exposing the implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, frameworks

I have created a framework in swift where I have made limited number of classes as public.The default header which will be present on creating any a framework has only version number info. But when I try to use the framework, I am not able to access even the public classes and methods.

Can anybody suggest how could we create a **swift framework without exposing the implementation.**

Answer (score 1):

It's how you pull a Swift Framework target into your app project that matters, not the header file. And if you are using Swift 3, you'll want to designate your classes as `open`, not `public`.

**Option #1: Add the Framework's .xcodeproj file to your app's project.**

You'll be able to edit the framework's source this way, but only only project can have it open at a time.

**Option #2: Import the Framework's .framework file to your app's project.**

You'll need to add this into your app's Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Also, you'll need to remember to reload it every time you make changes to the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.